# checking condition is true or false inside if statement in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to check if my message has some data or not and if it has some data it should do required process. How to do this inside `if` statement in node.js particularly?

Currently I am trying this:

```
if (messageBody && messageBody.x && messageBody.y && messageBody.z =='true'){
    do this
}
```

But it does not enter the `if` block and exits.

Comment: Then, either (`messageBody` or `messageBody.x` or `messageBody.y` **has falsy** value) or `messageBody.z is not "true"`

Comment: If it doesn't enter the body of the if, then the condition is false.

Comment: Remove the string == 'true' check. It's not helpful and may be causing your problems. You do realize that every one of these properties has to exist to enter the condition, right?

Comment: @ChrisSharp it might be a valid check...or not. OP has to provide more context here because we can't really say which part of the condition makes the whole condition false without guessing.

Comment: @vlaz it very well might be. But to get into the conditional it's not necessary and he's almost certainly either trying to use it as a boolean or passing in some fake boolean, which is bad practice anyway.

Comment: Can you post what you are getting for `messageBody `.

Comment: @ChrisSharp removing '==true' worked for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @techquestions you’re welcome

Answer (score 0):

Conditional statements are not different on a Node.js and a browser environment.
Your conditional statement looks quite strict and that last strict comparison operator `messageBody.z == 'true'` may need reviewing as you are performing an implicit cast on an equality check over a string literal.